# How to add custom link with store url in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

How to add custom url with store url (Base URL) in magamenu - magento 2. I try {{base_url}} but not working

[image]

Comment: Unless your store is installed under a subfolder (e.g. yourstore.com/magento), I think you can just add `/` in front of it. It would work in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest using:

```
{{store url=crazy-clown-contact-lenses-pair.html}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can't. This field is for static links that you will input (ex: https://example.com/path).

You can override the renderer code which use this datum, to complete link when it matches with a pattern which you will define. For example : {{ baseurl }}/your-link.